# ErrorException array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Tags: laravel

```
   public function  goesWellWith(Request $request)
        {
            $seo_url = $request->seo_url;
            $product = $this->product->getByAny('seo_url',$request->seo_url)->first();
            $categories = $this->product->getProductCategories($product->id);
            $category_ids = [];
            $products = [];
    
            if(count($categories) > 0){
                $category_ids = array_column($categories, 'term_id');
            }
    
            if(count($category_ids) > 0){
    
                $get_fillter_product = $this->product->getProductByFilter([
                    'recommended' => "on"
                ],$category_ids);
    
                foreach($get_fillter_product as $single_product){
    
                        $categoryProductList = [
                            'title' => $single_product->title,
                            'sub_title' => $single_product->sub_title,
                            'first_image' => $single_product->first_image?$single_product->first_image->full_size_directory: null,
                            'second_image' => $single_product->second_image?$single_product->second_image->full_size_directory: null,
                            'seo_url' => $single_product->seo_url
                        ];
    
                        $category_ids [] = $categoryProductList;
                }
            }
   
            return response()->json(compact('category_ids'));
    
        }
```

//

-

### List item

when i hit the url in insomnia to check i got this ErrorException array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given//

i got the error in this line of code

```
if(count($categories) > 0){
                $category_ids = array_column($categories, 'term_id');
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your code from this

```
$categories = $this->product->getProductCategories($product->id);
```

To

```
$categories = $this->product->getProductCategories($product->id)->toArray();
```

Comment: i got errors from this code ,,,,    if(count($categories) > 0){
                $category_ids = array_column($categories, 'term_id');
            }

Comment: have you tried my suggestion? it is because your `$categories` is an object. you have to change it to array first. as your error said `expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`

Comment: yes sir i tried the one you suggested , it's not working . but  i checked it again now its working . i made a mistake . thanks sir

Comment: if you used the code I suggested and it worked, kindly accept my answer. thank you :)

Comment: Thank you sir.  Finally it worked!  With the help of your suggestions.